# \DeclareUrlCommand with optional second argument

Tags: hyperref, urls

Creating a hyperlinked [DOI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_object_identifier) is possible:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\DeclareUrlCommand\adoi{\def\UrlLeft##1\UrlRight{\href{http://dx.doi.org/##1}{DOI:##1}}}%
\begin{document}
\adoi{56%78}
\end{document}
```

But I need something like `\adoi[1%2]{56%78}`: I would like to check whether the optional argument was used. If it was not given, `\adoi{56%78}` can be used as it is, but otherwise the equivalent to `\href{http://dx.doi.org/56%78}{DOI:1%2}` should result. Problem: How do I `\DeclareUrlCommand` with an optional second argument? I did not find a solution in the [hyperref manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf), but maybe I searched for the wrong keywords?

(What would that be good for anyway? There are [short DOIs](http://shortdoi.org/), and `\adoi[shortdoi]{longdoi}` would keep the information in the source file and provide the opportunity to decide later which DOI to use while linking to the long DOI, which would also be visible when hovering the mouse over the "DOI:..." in the pdf.)

Comment: Do you mean: `\usepackage{xparse}`, then `\NewDocumentCommand{\adoi}{mo}{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{\url{http://dx.doi.org/#1}}{\href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{DOI:#2}}}`, and then: `\adoi{no-optional-arg}` vs `\adoi{yes-optional-arg}[Yes]`?

Comment: @jon: Not quite: I mean `\NewDocumentCommand{\adoi}{mo}{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{\href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{DOI‌​:#1}}{\href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{DOI:#2}}}` (and the optional argument should be the first one, not the second), but that does not work for e.g. `\adoi[1%2]{56%78}` because the urls are not read verbatim.